# How do I split a template literal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component created with react-circular-progress bar and I want to split a line into two, in order to style them differently later. Also they have to be in different lines. But I can't figure out how to split them or add styles.

I have tried everything that I could think of in this line: `` text={`${value}${unit}`} ``

```
function circleProgress({ value, unit, percents, color, key }) {


    return (
        <CircularProgressbar
            key={key}
            percentage={percents}
            text={`${value}${unit}`}
            initialAnimation= {true}
            circleRatio={0.7}   
            styles={{
                root: {
                    margin: '0.5em'
                },
            }}
        />
    )
```

Comment: It'd be helpful if you told us what "I have tried everything that I could think of in this line" constitutes so we don't repeat solutions you've already tried.

Comment: Kind of depends on what `CircularProgressbar` does with `text`. Does it accept a React element or just a string?

Comment: Which CircularProgressBar component are you using

Comment: I'm using this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-circular-progressbar

Answer (score 2):

If the `text` prop can accept JSX to render, then you could do that:

```
return (
    <CircularProgressbar
        key={key}
        percentage={percents}
        text={(
            <div>
                <div>{value}</div>
                <div>{unit}</div>
            </div>
        )}
        initialAnimation= {true}
        circleRatio={0.7}   
        styles={{
            root: {
                margin: '0.5em'
            },
        }}
    />
)
```

The above is just an example, it's unclear exactly what your formatting requirements are. But since you're working with JSX it can be just about whatever you want.

Edit: since the component you're using actually renders SVG you would probably want to pass in valid SVG JSX, maybe something similar to this:

```
return (
    <CircularProgressbar
        key={key}
        percentage={percents}
        text={(
            <g>
                <text>{value}</text>
                <text y="24">{unit}</text>
            </g>
        )}
        initialAnimation= {true}
        circleRatio={0.7}   
        styles={{
            root: {
                margin: '0.5em'
            },
        }}
    />
)
```

Answer (score 1):

As [jered](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4897779/jered) pointed out, it's unclear what result you want, but if you simply want to be able to split them into two lines, you can use a linebreak `\n` in-between the variables and split them later.  I think [jered](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4897779/jered)'s answer is more flexible since you can pass in a custom styled component, but if you component doesn't accept JSX for that prop then this might help.

```js
var val1 = "test";
var val2 = "tset";
var combined = `${val1}\n${val2}`;

console.log(`Combined: ${combined}`);
console.log('Split');
console.log(combined.split(/\n/));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a prepackaged component which takes a string as props, only one element is being rendered from that string. If you really want to use this package, the most direct solution would be to edit the source for the component.  If you take a look at the [main component in this package's Github](https://github.com/kevinsqi/react-circular-progressbar/blob/master/src/CircularProgressbar.tsx) you can see the relevant portion of the render method:

```
        {text ? (
          <text className={classes.text} style={styles.text} x={CENTER_X} y={CENTER_Y}>
            {text}
          </text>
        ) : null}
```

Which you could essentially duplicate to add another text element called myText or whatever you'd like with its own styles.

```
        {text ? (
          <text className={classes.text} style={styles.text} x={CENTER_X} y={CENTER_Y}>
            {text}
          </text>
        ) : null}
        //CENTER_X and CENTER_Y will need to be re-computed to position your new text properly, or it could be done with CSS.
        {myText ? (
          <text className={classes.myText} style={styles.myText} x={CENTER_X} y={CENTER_Y}>
            {myText}
          </text>
        ) : null}
```

As this component uses defaultProps and TypeScript you will need to define your new prop in the declarations at the beginning of the file:

```
type CircularProgressbarDefaultProps = {
  strokeWidth: number;
  className: string;
  text: string;
  myText: string,
  background: boolean;
  backgroundPadding: number;
  initialAnimation: boolean;
  counterClockwise: boolean;
  circleRatio: number;
  classes: {
    root: string;
    trail: string;
    path: string;
    text: string;
    myText: string,
    background: string;
  };
  styles: {
    root?: object;
    trail?: object;
    path?: object;
    text?: object;
    myText?: object;
    background?: object;
  };
};
```

and

```
  static defaultProps: CircularProgressbarDefaultProps = {
    strokeWidth: 8,
    className: '',
    text: '',
    myText: '',
    background: false,
    backgroundPadding: 0,
    initialAnimation: false,
    counterClockwise: false,
    circleRatio: 1,
    classes: {
      root: 'CircularProgressbar',
      trail: 'CircularProgressbar-trail',
      path: 'CircularProgressbar-path',
      text: 'CircularProgressbar-text',
      background: 'CircularProgressbar-background',
    },
    styles: {
      root: {},
      trail: {},
      path: {},
      text: {},
      myText: {},
      background: {},
    },
  };
```

You could then use myText just like you would use the built-in text prop.  The most annoying part will probably be positioning it properly, as it uses SVG elements which have their own coordinate attributes which you'd need to either manipulate in the component file yourself or try to override with CSS as indicated in my comment.  It may be more trouble than it's worth for a simple color contrast, but that's just my opinion.

Hope this helps!

Edit: Actually I think jered's solution would work with accepted SVG elements, not sure if nesting  nodes would cause any issues but you could definitely insert them successfully.  Again the biggest hurdle is the styling/positioning.

Comment: Good catch on it being SVG, I didn't notice that ‍♂️I agree that they should go look at the library component source code when they need to figure this kind of stuff out.